# Getting names of function arguments

Tags: javascript

We have a function:

```
function Foo (a,b,c) {
  return a + b + c;
}
```

Need to get names of Foo arguments outside from the function. The result should be:

```
Array['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`Foo.arguments` returns `null`.

The only way I see is calling `Foo.toString()` and then parsing the result.

Is there another more correct way to get the names?

Comment: Can you refactor the function to receive an object with structure `{ 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': null }`? Code smell?

Comment: No, it is a function from dependency and i cannot refact it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using `Function#toString` seems to be the way to go:

```
 const str = Foo.toString();
 const args = str.substr(str.indexOf("("), str.indexOf(")")).split(",").map(it => it.trim());
```